# After uploading an image, how can I get the URL to that image from the path?

Tags: javascript, php, image, file-upload

I would like to retrieve the URL to an image so that I can display the image that the user has successfully uploaded in my project. However, upon testing I only have an absolute path. What is the best way to trim this down to a relative path in relation to the URL of the website?

For instance, if I have this: `"/home/teonnyn/public_html/app/webroot/thumb/Teonnyn/thumb_ZB6pEaz.jpg"`

I would want to convert it to `"url.com/thumb/Teonnyn/"` and so on. So far, I have a JSON output string that returns the successful upload to Javascript:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$output = array("thumb" => $ThumbResult, "image" => $FileResult);

$echo = json_encode($output);

echo $echo;
```

That produces a message containing the absolutes for the thumbnail and the image. It is received by Javascript:

```
done: function(e, data) {
    console.log("Done!");
    var Obj = data.result;
    var parse = JSON.parse(Obj);
    console.log(parse.thumb);
}
```

at which point, I can access either .thumb or .image easily, but I am unsure how to finish the conversion steps.

Comment: you can replace `eonnyn/public_html/app/webroot/` with your `URL.com` before getting output using str_replace() function.